# Gin config - ValueError raised even in examples

Tags: python, config

I want to use gin config for a project, but even the most basic example raises a `ValueError: No configurable matching {}`.

I copied this example straight from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-worrying-about-configs-with-gin-218562dd5c91)

*config.gin*

```
make_drink.drink_name = "G&T"
make_drink.ingredients = ["Gin", "Tonic", "Lemon"]
make_drink.ice = False
```

*main.py*

```
import gin
gin.parse_config_file("./config.gin")

@gin.configurable
def make_drink(drink_name:str, ingredients:list, ice:bool=False):
    print(f"New drink called: {drink_name}")
    print(f"Drink contains: " + ", ".join(ingredients))
    if ice is True:
        print("With ice")
    else:
        print("Without ice")

make_drink()
```

The result is always the same:

```
ValueError: No configurable matching 'make_drink'.
  In file "./config.gin", line 1
    make_drink.drink_name = "G&T"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, i got it. Apparently one must put the `gin.parse_config_file("./config.gin")` command in the main.

```
import gin

@gin.configurable
def make_drink(drink_name:str, ingredients:list, ice:bool=False):
    print(f"New drink called: {drink_name}")
    print(f"Drink contains: " + ", ".join(ingredients))
    if ice is True:
        print("With ice")
    else:
        print("Without ice")

if __name__=='__main__':
    gin.parse_config_file("./config.gin")
    make_drink()
```

If anyone could explain to me, why it does not work when i put at after the import, i would appreciate that.

Comment: Same issue here. You solution solved it. I'm not sure why I have struggled so much with that and found no clear answer/explanation to that.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. But a friend of mine told me, that my solution is unnecessary. In the GIN-Config file you have to change „__init__“ to „init“ without changing the Python file at all.